# Sorting string column in Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I have a `status` field in my elastic search index which can take values `Open,Closed,Clear,Intermediate,Ready for Approval`. Right now, I have created a visualization and sorted this field descending based on the Term. What I want to achieve is - I want this to be sorted in this particular order `Open,Clear,Intermediate,Ready for Approval,Closed`.

How do I achieve this? One option I am thinking is creating a scripted field and prefixing with integer column, but I am not sure if I will be able to filter the visualization later?

Answer (score 0):

If this list of possible values is a static list of known values, there is another way to define your visualization with a little more manual configuration. Just replace your `terms aggregation` with a `filters aggregation` and add custom filters for the possible values like so:

[image: Kibana 5 Filters aggregation for status]

Kibana will respect the order of your filters in the visualization. From a performance perspective, this should also be better than using a scripted field...